# Why is it a bad idea to escape HTML before escaping SQL?

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, html

From the security perspective (and not usability as it's discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648430/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-escape-html-before-inserting-into-a-database-instead-of-upon), why is it a bad idea to escape HTML before escaping SQL?

Comment: I think you may have misread the question and answers.  I don't see anything about escaping SQL or SQL injection in there.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to *Preventing code injection without limiting user input?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23501225/53114)

Comment: @Gumbo now thinking... what about the semicolon? Escaping HTML will introduce a semicolon (e.g. $quot;), and could not be this used to exploit the DB?

Comment: @yzT It would only appear within string literals, where it wouldn’t be interpreted as statement separator.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to database security, it's irrelevant. SQL doesn't care if the string contains raw HTML or escaped HTML or whatever.

But as explained in the other question, this messes up the data. I would actually consider it a bug.